# Returning XML/JSON in Jersey

Tags: java, rest, jersey

```
@GET @Path("/ids/{printerid}")
@Produces({"application/json", "application/xml"})
public Printer getPrinter(@PathParam("printerid") String printerId) { ... }
```

is a piece of a code example found here: https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/jaxrs-resources.html#d0e2089

What I understand is:

- the method `getPrinter` is called when the `HTTP method GET` is called on the path `/ids/{printerid}`
- the method `Produces` either a `json` or an `xml` result
- the method returns an `Object` of type Printer, identified by the ID provided in the `URI`

What I don't understand is, how the returned Printer is represented as an `xml/json` document. We return a Printer in this method, so how do we get an `xml/json` file from that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the whole idea of Jersy layer / spring controller, they encapsulate it and convert the class to JSON. You can have the same result with Gson

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(printerObject);
System.out.println(json);
```

Not sure if Jersy is using Gson, but the logic will be probably the same

Comment: Ok. As I understand it, I don't have to do anything for the conversion itself.
Now suppose I call a method, which produces XML, how do I display it in the client (browser) in my case. When I call the method, nothing is displayed

Comment: Check in the web browser network console, check the response body or use fiddler to see what data you get from the server and make sure you parse it correctly

Comment: thanks. It seems that there is an internal server error. At least I vaguely know where I should look now

Answer (score 1):

When you request for a service from clien side you always mentioned content type there which indicates the response accepted in xml or json.

```
$http({
        method: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json",
        url: baseUrl + '/xyz' + id
      }).success(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
        // you can also use
        console.log(JSON.stringify(response);
      }).error(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on "Content-type" in the request, jersey will decide the representation.

There are many frameworks that provide support for xml/json representation for jersey. Jackson and JAXB are very popular and efficient frameworks for JSON and XML processing in jersey.

Take a look to official Jersey documentation for different frameworks : 
https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/media.html

You can find many articles related to XML and JSON support in jersey here :
http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/jax-rs-tutorials/

Answer (score 0):

You need to send the header "accept" in the request with the desired value: "application/json" or "application/xml".